# TinkerPop 3.1.0 Console - Display stack trace?

Tags: stack-trace, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm currently using TinkerPop 3.1.0 Console Incubating, and everytime there is an option

`Display stack trace? [yN]`

I cannot enter "y" or "N" to show or not show the Stack Trace. It simply goes to a new line and gives you no chance to enter the yN answer. This means I cannot do any debugging regarding my gremlin scripts, commands etc.

You can see an example in the following picture: [Gremlin Console Stack Trace Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWU7e.png)

I have encountered this issue on two separate machines running TinkerPop 3.1.0 Console Incubating, and did not have the same issue with the gremlin-2.6.0 Console version I was testing prior.

Has anyone else had this issue? Is there any possibility of a quick fix? Or do I need to wait for a new release and see if that fixes the problem?

Thanks in advance. - M

Comment: you're using windows i take it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a side effect of a long-standing [Groovy bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6453). If you modify the `gremlin.bat` and remove the `-Djline.terminal=none` option, the ability to view the stack trace is restored, however you'll miss out on the other abilities that are pretty nice, like using the arrow keys.

Comment: Fixed my issue :) Thanks Jason!